# How to cool down a warehouse?

Tags: airflow, hvac, cooling

I have a warehouse ( 36m x 14.4m x 10m ) that I want to keep it under 30 degrees Celsius but everyday the temperature will goes above that. It has two turbine ventilator that I don't know the specification and for the ventilation it only relies to two rolling doors ( 3x2m ).

I have a thought that it is caused by bad airflow in the warehouse so
I have an idea to add 3pcs of 8ft HVLS Fan and adding 5 more turbine ventilators. But will it works because I will have to do a big investments to that fans.

I live in Jakarta, Indonesia. And the ambient temperature ranges from 28 - 35 degree C in the afternoon.

Comment: Doubt you are going to cool to less than outside air temperature with fans.

Comment: @NaufalB: Please edit your question to state the outside air temperature. There is nothing in your question or user profile to give a clue about your location and climate. Are you in Ghana or Greenland?

Comment: You normally pair those fans, one pulling air and one exhausting. That way you don't suck the rolling doors into the building when you close them. Passive turbines wouldn't be a good idea along unless you only plan on running the fans for a couple hours, and can manage on turbines the rest of the day.  I've worked in a warehouse where you couldn't get any doors open with a crowbar if you put all the fans on exhaust, which is just plain stupid and dangerous. Wire the fans so that can't happen.

Comment: Put a switch on the roll doors so they have to be open all the way before the fans can be run unpaired, ie., both exhausting.

Answer (score 3):

> keep it under 30 degrees Celcius but everyday the temperature will goes above that

No amount of ventilation when it's hot out is going to fix that.  In fact, more ventilation will make that worse.  Ventilation will only cool the warehouse when the outside temperature is less than the inside temperature.

One way ventilation can help, if it's managed properly, is to ventilate aggressively when it is cooler out than in, then NOT ventilate when the outside temperature goes above the inside temperature.  Whether that is feasible depends on a number of factors you haven't told us.  It may not be acceptable to decrease the daytime ventilation sufficiently due to fresh air requirements, doors must be open, etc.  Also, with little insulation, the warehouse will heat up when its hot outside anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, if you only have the fans and no hvac is to consider a « puits canadienne ».

The idea is a pipe or pipes in parallel buried underground about 2m or 6 feet down, where the ground temperature is lower than air ambient - depends on the season of course and country... (in Switzerland the air ambient can be -10 deg C and underground +5 deg C , used this for the air ventilation on the house).

There are sites which will help with sizing the pipes and issues of moisture getting trapped in the pipes must be addressed : legionnaires disease.

If I find a site I will add it ...